# Icon Buttons without Titles in Flutter's Cupertino Tab bar Widget

Tags: flutter

Would anyone be in a position to know how to make Cupertino Bottom tab bar views with icon buttons only and NO titles in Flutter?
Like the way the Facebook and Twitter bottom bar apps on iOS are they only have icons no title below the icons in the bottom bar.
In flutter using Cupertino Tab bar we are forced to always put a title in the BottomNavigationBar items. Is there a work around to only have icons/icon buttons without titles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry I’m on mobile. 
You can do like this.

```
BottomNavigationBarItem(
     icon: Icon(Icons.home),
     title: Container(),
)
```